# how can I change this condition to that I want

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a condition with two value. if the condition equal to `0` it return `Absent` and if equal to `1` it returns `present`.
now I want to add the third value into my condition. if the condition equal to `3` it returns `Unacceptable absent`.

this is my conditions with two value:

```
(status >= 1 ? "Present" : "Absent")
```

how can I change the condition?

Comment: Use a `switch` statement.

Comment: or if else (cant do it in a single line as far as i am aware)

Comment: What if status is 2?

Comment: this question might duplicate... refer this : stackoverflow.com/a/12484146/10289046

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you could add a failsafe status as "NA" and do it as follows :

```
status == 0 ? "Absent" : status == 1? "Present" : status == 3? "Unacceptable Absent" : "NA";
```

Comment: never seen that before! thats the best answer in my opinon!

Answer (score 17):

Use a lookup dictionary.

```
//Initialized once in your program
var lookup = new Dictionary<int,string>
{
    { 0, "Absent"},
    { 1, "Present"},
    { 3, "Unacceptably Absent" }
};

//Call this whenever you need to convert a status code to a string
var description = lookup[status];
```

Answer (score 14):

Using nested ternary operators sacrifices readability for brevity. I recommend using the humble `switch` statement instead:

```
string foo(int status)
{
    switch (status)
    {
        case 0:
            return "Present";
        case 1:
            return "Absent";
        case 3:
            return "Unacceptable absent";
        default:
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(status), $"What kind of person passes {status}?");
    }
}
```

Comment: With C# 8 _Switch Expressions_ this becomes even more usable.

Answer (score 4):

i recommend something more readable to  @Shubhams approach like this:

```
string foo(int status)
{
    if (status == 0)
        return ("Present");
    else if (status == 1)
        return ("Absent");
    else if (status == 2)
        return ("Somthing else");
    else
        return ("Outside");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
status >= 1 ?(status >2?"third Value":"Present") : "Absent"
```

Like that

Comment: interessting never considered nesting these. It works, seems rather unreadable to me tho. But it works so here is an upvote

Comment: don't nest too many ..it will make code look worse.....but good enough for your case

Answer (score 3):

Best approach is to get rid of if else conditions as much as you can and this is how you do that:

```
public static class AppStartupConfig
{
    public static Dictionary<int,string> AttendanceStatus = new Dictionary<int,string>();

    public static void InitAppStuff(){
        //Bring basic data from database
        //fill the list looping data for e.g:
        if(AttendanceStatus.Count == 0){
           AttendanceStatus.Add(0,"Absent");
           AttendanceStatus.Add(1,"Present");
           AttendanceStatus.Add(3,"Unacceptable absent");
        }
    }
}
```

and to use it you won't need any if else anymore through out your app, just run this method at the point where your application is started and then just get your value by providing the key to this dictionary like:

```
    AppStartupConfig.InitAppStuff();
    Console.WriteLine(AppStartupConfig.AttendanceStatus[3]); //returns respective string value
```

[C# fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/DzIitq)

Comment: Can you explain me why its best to avoid if else?

Comment: If else may seem simple yet it takes much of processing cost as well as some detail information can be [found here too, to know why to avoid it as well](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/206822)

Answer (score 2):

```
(status == 0 ? "Absent" : status == 1 ? "Present" : status == 3 ? "Unacceptable" : "Unknown status")
```

You can nest the operators, this way you kind of create a large if & else tree that's, in my opinion, sort of readable. A switch would be more readable.

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like this:

```
status == 0 ? "Absent" : status == 1 ? "Present" : "Unacceptable"
```

But this code style isn't good readable. Better to use dictionary or switch/case statement etc.

Answer (score 1):

Like that:

```
status == 0 ? "Absent" : status == 1 ? "present" : status == 3 ? "Unacceptable Absent" : 1==1
```

I hope to help you.

Answer (score 1):

If you have to stick on with Ternary operator, you can modify the code to satisfy three values.

```
string tmp = (status == 0 ? "Absent" : (status == 1 ? "Present" : "NA"));
```